# Could not uploded the image into folder using PHP

Tags: php, file, file-upload, image-uploading

i could not upload file into directory using php. I am explaining my code below.

```
$_FILES=array('picture'=>array('name' => 'IMG-20161121-WA0000.jpg','type' => ' image/png','tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpSb6a53', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 119198));
$imageFieldName = 'picture';
$imagePath = "admin/uploads/";
uploadImage($_FILES,$imageFieldName,$imagePath,function($image){
    print_r($image);exit;
}
public function uploadImage($files, $imageFieldName, $imageDirPath, $callback) {
        $result = array();
        ;
        $imageName = generateRandomNumber() . '_' . $_FILES[$imageFieldName]['name'];
       // echo($_FILES[$imageFieldName]['tmp_name']);exit;
        $target_dir = $imageDirPath;
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($imageName);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $result['msg'] = "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $result['num'] = 0;
            $callback($result);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($_FILES[$imageFieldName]["size"] > 500000) {
          //  echo 'fileSize';exit;
            $result['msg'] = "Sorry, file size is large.";
            $result['num'] = 0;
            $callback($result);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if (($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "JPG") && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
            $result['msg'] = "Sorry, only .jpg,.jpeg and .png files are allowed.";
            $result['num'] = 0;
            $callback($result);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $result['msg'] = "Sorry, Your file could not uploaded.";
            $result['num'] = 0;
            $callback($result);
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imageFieldName]['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                $result['msg'] = "Image has uploaded successfully.";
                $result['num'] = 1;
                $result['img'] = $imageName;
                $callback($result);
            } else {
                $result['msg'] = "Sorry, Your Image could not uploaded to the directory.";
                $result['num'] = 0;
                $callback($result);
            }
        }
    }
```

After selecting file i am getting

> `$_FILES=array('name' => 'IMG-20161121-WA0000.jpg','type' => '
>   image/png','tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpSb6a53', 'error' => 0, 'size' =>
>   119198);`

as input.

But i am getting the message

> `Array ( [msg] => Sorry, Your Image could not uploaded to the
>   directory. [num] => 0 )

while print_r. Here i need to upload the image into folder. Please help me.

Comment: check if target directory writable

Comment: @RomaRush : yes,it is writeable.

Comment: i have directory path like this. `API/normaluser.php` in this file i am using fileupload code and i want to upload `admin/uploads/` folder.Both `API and admin` folder inside one root folder and inside `admin` folder `upload` folder is present where i need to upload the images.

Comment: i think you need to try to define full absolute path for you target directory. and you cannot define $_FILES manually, files must be uploaded

Comment: @RomaRush : Can you please write the path for directory as per my above comment.

Comment: maybe `$imagePath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/admin/uploads/'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128945/discussion-between-subhra-and-roma-rush).

Comment: sorry, i have no time for this

Answer (score -1):

Did you check your `php.ini` settings for file upload?

Check the values for

```
upload_max_filesize 
post_max_size 
memory_limit
```

Maybe they are set too small.

Comment: This function is working fine for some other perpose with same directory. But when i am uploading by writing like this `$_FILES=array('name' => 'IMG-20161121-WA0000.jpg','type' => '
  image/png','tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpSb6a53', 'error' => 0, 'size' =>
  119198);`,its giving the error message.